# How can I leave an ally out of a Fireball?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, area-of-effect, content-identification

I *think* I saw an option (probably a feat) that you can use to not affect an ally with an area spell. Now I cannot find it, even though I checked all Wizard and Sorcerer metamagic feats.

Is there such an option?

Comment: @Raj A negative is better off an answer. It resolves the question albeit perhaps not too satisfactory. And of course they can be difficult to fully demonstrate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Two options that somewhat work are found under the [Magaambyan Attendant](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=29)

There is [Tempest-Sun Redirection](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1108) and [Tempest-Sun Shielding](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1113)

> If the next action you use is to Cast a Spell from your spell slots that damages other creatures, you can bend some of that spell’s offensive energy, protecting allies in the area and boosting your own defenses against certain foes. Select any number of targets of the spell and reduce the spell’s damage to those targets by an amount equal to the spell’s level. Until your next turn, when one of those targets damages you, that damage is reduced by twice the spell’s level.

> **Trigger** You or an ally within 30 feet takes damage.
>
> You transform unrealized spell energy into a protective shield. If you’re a spontaneous spellcaster, expend a spell slot; if you’re a prepared spellcaster, expend a spell prepared in a spell slot. Reduce the triggering damage by an amount equal to four times the level of the expended slot or spell.

---

I found these by trying various searches on Archives of Nethys, in this case the search "[spell area damage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?Query=spell%20area%20damage&Filter=111111111111111&AllTerms=True)" worked.

I have marked this as a Community Wiki answer, so that others may contribute to it freely.